# Force Exim to deliver mail as if it were remote

Tags: email, exim

I'm messing around with a mail server on a VPS. I can send and receive mail between my local account using `exim user@mydomain.com`. I can also send mail remotely to `me@gmail.com` (of course I get a bounce back message because I don't have PTR, SPF, DKIM, etc. but gmail is receiving it at least).

However, I'm having trouble sending mail from gmail to my mailserver. So, my question is:

**Is there any way I can send mail using exim, such that I force the mail to leave my machine and use DNS, instead of just being delivered locally**. By this, I mean that I want to send mail between `user1@mydomain.com` and `user2@mydomain.com`. I want to do this so that I can see the logs on both ends.

(I'm new here, so please let me know if this is not on topic.)

Comment: Please provide details about the failures gmail is reporting.  If you can log on to a remote server.  Try connecting to your mail server and sending email by hand.  Given what is missing, it is probable gMail has no idea where to send your email. You VPS provider may be blocking access.

Comment: @billthor the issues are with my mx records, but I'm still curious about an exim configuration that will allow me to do this.

Comment: Unless you use a relay server and a second configuration, it won't be possible.  You would generate a send loop.  I don't know of any mail server that would allow you do send to the local server by sending to a second server first. It breaks the design of SMTP entirely.